# Detect periodes of irregular patterns in time series data

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection, signal-processing

This plot shows hourly time series data of a households power usage. The house is only occupied for short periods.

**What simple alg. or technique can I use to find the start of these irregularities?**

The amplituede of these irregularities will mostly by above the mean of the previous hours, but the duration can vary. Also, the "human noise" will be present in these periodes.

[image]

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1142 has many constructive suggestions that could be applied to this series.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20612 looks like a duplicate question: indeed, it concerns an even more challenging version of your series (with a great many such unusual episodes to detect).  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/261115 is also related and gives an approach based on the increase in variability in the high signal (the "human noise").

Comment: This is great, thanks. Didn't find these while googling.